# Variable does not increment in loop that reads file

Tags: c, fgets, scanf

My code reads input in the following format:

- The first line has just a number
- The other lines have a number and 4 strings

The first line tells the number of following lines.

After reading the file, I want to verify if the number of lines read is the same as specified in the first line. In order to achieve it, I am trying to use a variable count_lines, incrementing it at each iteration of the while loop.

```
FILE  *fp;
char   line[MAXLINELEN];
int count_lines = 0;
char city[50], continent[13], cultural[1], outdoors[1];
int total_lines, id;
```

...

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
{
        if (count_lines == 0)
        {
            sscanf(line, "%d", &total_lines);
        nodes2 = calloc(sizeof(node), total_lines);
        }
    else if (sscanf(line, "%d %s %s %s %s", ...)
        {
            /* code (previously some malloc and strcopy stuff, but the error occurs even without this part of the code) */
        }
        else
        {
            /* code */
        }

    count_lines++;
    printf("point \n");
    printf("%d\n", count_lines);    
}
```

Data example:

-bash-4.1$ cat places

```
3
1      City1         Continent1 Y         Y
2      City2         Continent1 Y         Y
3      City3         Continent1     Y         N
```

However, this is the output of running the code:

```
point
1
point
1
point
1
point
1
point
1
point
1
point
1
point
1
point
1
point
1
point
1
point
1
```

I verified that the problem has to do with the else if part. If I comment this part, the counting works correctly. However, I could not figure out why this is happening.

What's wrong with the code?

Note: As this is part of an assignment, I cannot post the whole code.
I omitted irrelevant parts with a       /* code */ comment.

Comment: Please post a complete program that shows the problem. The real code probably has a typo or something important that you omitted.

Comment: Most likely your `sscanf` goes out of bounds and overwrites some memory it is not supposed to overwrite, which includes memory area containing `count_lines` variable. This accidentally resets `count_lines` to zero on each iteration. You have to post your complete `sscanf` and everything related to it. And, I'm afraid, we'll need to see the actual data you are trying to `sscanf`, i.e. the contents of `line`.

Comment: But how are `city`, `continent`, `cultural`, `outdoors` declared?

Comment: Also 'line' - we need to see the data decs.

Comment: I apologize. As this is part of an assignment, I cannot post the whole code. I thought that part would be enough. I don't know what to do... maybe I shouldn't have posted in the first place.

Comment: Produce a program that shows the same problem but doesn't have any stuff that is irrelevant. For example if the stuff you'd posted were enough you could just fill in the `...` with `int main() { ` and a function call. Check that it still shows the problem.

Comment: Right, I figured out the problem. I haven't accepted my answer so fat because I have to wait 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy` copies second argumet to first argument. In your code you seem to assume the reverse

```
char *cont_temp = malloc(strlen(continent) + 1);    
strcpy(city, cont_temp);
```

In this case you are copying *from* `cont_temp` to `city`. But `cont_temp` at this point contains garbage, while `city` contains the data you just read from file. That's one of the problems. Apparently it should be

```
strcpy(cont_temp, city);
```

shouldn't it?

However, I don't understand why you use `strlen(continent)` to determine the memory size, but then suddenly switch to working with `city`. That's another problem.

Comment: That's true. I was thinking in the continent, switched to city to test and forgot to change it. So I inverted the order and created the *char with the right size. But it seems that the problem persistis. Any ideia?

Comment: By the way, if I comment out the body of the else if, the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that cultural and outdoors have size 1, so there's no enough space for the new line character. Defining them with size 2 solves the problem.